# Rails OAuth: Can't get refresh token from microsoft office 365 rest api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, office365, omniauth

I'm trying to figure out how to get the refresh token from an office365 user with omniauth.

In my `devise.rb` file I have tried two different ways but to no avail:

```
config.omniauth :microsoft_office365, ENV['OFFICE365_APP_ID'], ENV['OFFICE365_SECRET'],
                  access_type: 'offline',
                  scope: 'https://outlook.office.com/calendars.read'
```

```
config.omniauth :microsoft_office365, ENV['OFFICE365_APP_ID'], ENV['OFFICE365_SECRET'],
                  scope: 'https://outlook.office.com/calendars.read, offline_access'
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the offline_access scope needn't be defined in `devise.rb`. All you have to do is add the scope in the Microsoft [Application Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com).

For me, the microsoft_office365 config line in `devise.rb` now looks like this:

```
  config.omniauth :microsoft_office365, ENV['OFFICE365_APP_ID'], ENV['OFFICE365_SECRET'],
                  scope: 'https://outlook.office.com/calendars.read'
```